# Functional bound on $\Bbb R \times \{0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let's define functional on $\Bbb R \times \{0\}$ as:

$$f((x, 0)) = -2x$$

I want to judge whether this functional is bounded assuming that on $R \times \{0\}$ we consider norm $\|x\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i|$.

**My work so far**

I'm not sure if my intuition is correct but I was trying to bound $f((x,0))$ somehow:

$$\|f((x,0))\|_1 = |-2x|=2|x|  $$

And here I stopped - I think that it should not be bounded, since $|x|$ it's not a bounded function on $\mathbb{R}$. So I took sequence $a_n = -n$ and then:

$$f((a_n, 0)) = 2a_n = 2n \rightarrow \infty$$

so this operator is not bounded. Am I correct with my justification?

Comment: when we call linear functionals bounded we mean that $|f(x)| \leq M |x|$ for each $x$, so here we have $M=2$ and it is bounded.

Comment: Ohh yes - I forgot about this definition. Is this also implying that $\|f\| = 2$?

Comment: you usually call an operator a functional if it acts on functions

Comment: yes $||f||=2$...

Comment: That's perfect thank you very much!